# Set name and description when uploading to Vimeo with PHP

Tags: php, upload, vimeo-api

I am new at Vimeo upload, and do some testing with the exemple scripts from PHP API (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php), and it works to uploading video!
But I can´t set the [body][name] and [body][description] with the script. I have tried to understand the explanation of "https://developer.vimeo.com/api", but I can´t get it right.

My question is:
How do I add name and description to my uploading video with my script? (pure PHP)

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Your must first upload the video and then edit it. (Sending the name and description)

The method is PATCH and the url is https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{videoId}

[Here I doit with Javascript](https://github.com/andrestntx/vimeo-upload), but essentially it's the same

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for editing a video is [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#PATCH/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D).

The php library has examples for making API calls [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#make-requests). And documentation on the upload system [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#upload-videos-from-the-server).

The return value of your upload request will contain the uri in the headers, specifically the `location` header like this:

`$response['headers']['location']`

As the editing documentation explains, you will need to make a `PATCH` request to this url, with the fields `name` and `description`.

In php, this looks like the following:

```
$response = $lib->upload($filename);
$lib->request($response['headers']['location'], array('name' => $name, 'description' => $description), 'PATCH');
```